# How to determine the PATH environment variable after executing cmd /c "command"?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to determine what the PATH environment variable was after I execute a batch file (vcvarsall.bat) by running

```
cmd /c "vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64 && echo %PATH%"
```

but what happens is not what I expect.  For example, if I run:

```
cmd /c "set PATH=test && echo %PATH%"
```

I just get the PATH of the host process, not "test" as I expected, as echo %PATH% should be running in the context of the child process, not the parent.  So, why does this happen, and how do I go about getting the result I'm after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cmd /c "set PATH=test && echo %PATH%"
```

will interpret `PATH` *before* it's changed. This is actually a neat trick to export environment variables outside of a `setlocal/endlocal` chunk with:

```
ste xyzzy=twisty
startlocal
set xyzzy=plugh
endlocal && set xyzzy=%xyzzy%
```

Normally (without the `&& xyzzy=...` bit, the `xyzzy` variable would still be the initial value of twisty after the block but the fact that the `%xyzzy%` is interpreted *before* the entire `endlocal` line while the `set` is actioned after the `endlocal` command, allows you to export the change.

If you want to interpret a variable after the `set`, you need delayed expansion:

```
cmd /v:on /c "set PATH=test && echo !PATH!"
```

The `/v:on` turns on delayed expansion and the use of `!` instead of `%` indicates that you want to use that delayed expansion.

Comment: Fails if delayed expansion is already enabled - see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8870200/1012053)

Answer (score 2):

The paxdiablo solution will not work if used when delayed expansion is enabled in the parent environment.

from a batch file

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
rem !PATH! below will get expanded in parent batch environment
cmd /v:on /c "set PATH=test && echo !PATH!"
```

or from the command line

```
cmd /v:on
rem !PATH! below will get expanded in parent batch environment
cmd /v:on /c "set PATH=test && echo !PATH!"
```

The simple solution is to escape the expansion so that it is delayed until you are in the new cmd environment.

```
cmd /v:on
rem This works whether or not delayed expansion is enabled in the parent environment
cmd /v:on /c "set PATH=test && echo ^!PATH^!"
```

Note that /v:on is still required in the 2nd cmd because cmd does not inherit the delayed expansion state from the parent environment.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting bitten by the [immediate expansion of variables](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/23/714650.aspx).

`cmd.exe` is not a good scripting language.

Comment: cmd.exe is not a scripting language at all.